# How to model flexible plate between two sticks solidworks

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, solidworks, solid-mechanics

I am following a paper on undulatory fin motion and trying to make a model of it in Solidworks.

The problem is stated as having two servo motors with two rays and a flexible rubber membrane between them.

My problem is that when I attach the rubber to the fin then the stepper motor is rotating in parallel, and not separately, without the rubber being flexible.

Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: *why* do you want it modelled in SW? Presumably not for manufacturing - for animation?

Comment: A link to your paper would help us. Reading this webpage might help you: https://releeps.tripod.com/cgi-bin/

Comment: yes animation and upload the model to Simulink i am reffering to this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7353395

Comment: You need the model of the membrane to reference the assembly.  Easiest way is to build the servo model assembly minus the membrane and then start a new part model from within the assembly.  Make a 3D sketch in the part and project the "two rays" into the sketch.

Comment: Accompanying video: https://youtu.be/brdSSw9aWTA

Comment: what kind of software is used in the video for the simulation?